# How to implement a Fourier Convolution layer in keras?

Tags: keras, cnn

I'm currently investigating the paper [FCNN: Fourier Convolutional Neural
Networks](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-71249-9_47). The main contribution of the paper is that CNN training is entirely shifted to the Fourier domain without loss of effectiveness. The proposed architecture looks as follows:

[image]

The authors state that the implementation was done in keras, however, it is not publicly available. I know I can define a Fourier transformation in the following way:

```
model.add(layers.Lambda(lambda v: tf.real(tf.spectral.rfft(v))))
```

But this is not a Fourier Convolution, right? How should I go from here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An FFT-based convolution can be broken up into 3 parts: an FFT of the input images and the filters, a bunch of element-wise products followed by a sum across input channels, and then an IFFT of the outputs ([Source](http://benanne.github.io/2014/05/12/fft-convolutions-in-theano.html)).

Or as it is written in the paper:

[image]

So, for a Fourier Convolution Layer you need to:

1. Take the input layer and transform it to the Fourier domain:

   `input_fft = tf.spectral.rfft2d(input)`
2. Take each kernel and transform it to the Fourier domain:

   `weights_fft = tf.spectral.rfft2d(layer.get_weights())`

   Note: The Fourier domain "images" for the input and the kernels need to be of the same size.
3. Perform element-wise multiplication between the input's Fourier transform and Fourier transform of each of the kernels:

   `conv_fft = keras.layers.Multiply(input_fft, weights_fft)`
4. Perform Inverse Fourier transformation to go back to the spatial domain.

   `layer_output = tf.spectral.irfft2d(conv_fft)`

Note: I used pseudo-code, it will probably needs some tuning for it to actually to work.

Comment: Did somebody able to implement this in a keras CNN code with tensorflow?